# JavaFX - Maintain Shape Borders after using Shape.union()

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

Is there a way to maintain the borders/strokes on a JavaFX Shape after using the union function? For example here is my code:

```
Shape rect = new Rectangle(150, 150);
rect.setFill(Color.WHITE);
rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
rect.setStrokeWidth(4);

Line line = new Line(0, 40, 150, 40);
line.setStrokeWidth(2);

Shape combined = Shape.union(line, rect);
combined.setFill(Color.WHITE);
combined.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
pane.getChildren().add(combined);
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

**Actual Output:**

[image: Actual Output]

Is there anyway that I can union the two together so that I can drag and drop them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is `combined.setFill(Color.WHITE);` ,because it clear all previous `shape` changes .

Try something like this

```
        Line line = new Line(0, 40, 150, 40);
        Shape rect = new Rectangle(150, 150);

        Shape combined = Shape.subtract(rect,line);
        combined.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        combined.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        rect.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rect.setStrokeWidth(4);

        line.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        line.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        pane.getChildren().add(combined);
```

out put will like be this

[image]

For more info about `shape.union,subtract,intersect` go [here](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/06/18/shapes-intersection-subtract-and-union-in-javafx-2-0/)

Comment: Yup!  The Shape.substract() instead of Shape.union() worked for me.  Thank you!